# Receiving variables in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

```
private function editForm():void {
                var event:DepManagementEvent = new DepManagementEvent("Edit Page",true);
                for each(var item:Object in parentDocument.deleteDataGrid.selectedItems) {
                    event.department = item["col3"];
                }
                dispatchEvent(event);
            }
```

I am able to access the parent datagrid and get the value of department... Now when I send to the other page how can I store the value which I am passing from here...

I am stuck on this.

Comment: Store where? send to a server? in a sqlite db? in a text file? need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dispatching a custom event on this file, then you probably want to use the Event metadata tag. The other page can then `this.addEventListener(event, eventHandlerFunction);` where the eventHandlerFunction(event:Event) will be able to receive the event and gain access to the information sent from the original page. 
You may now save the data on the second page within the eventHandlerFunction